# Calling Code Behind Function and passing arguments

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have asp.net text box where I am calling the code behind function through __postback but I also want to pass text of the text box which is calling __postback function.
Here is my text box.

```
       <asp:TextBox Width="400px" ID="txtExtraRooms" MaxLength="3" 
        onkeypress="__doPostBack(this.name,'OnKeyPress');" runat="server" 
       Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

And my code behind where I want to get entered text of text box with id="txtExtraRooms"

```
      Dim ctrlName As String = Request.Params(Page.postEventSourceID)
      Dim args As String = Request.Params(Page.postEventArgumentID)
     // here I want text of text box with id "txtExtraRooms"
    If ((ctrlName = txtExtraRooms.UniqueID) _
                AndAlso (args = "OnKeyPress")) Then
          TextBox2_OnKeyPress(ctrlName, args)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate for any asp.net event has the 1st argument as the "sender" which holds the reference to the control raising the event.
For textbox, you should use the TextChanged event rather than doing the postback (which will require state management as well).

Add an AutoPostback=true on textbox and provide the TextChanged=handler. The page postback will happen, although handling will be on the provided handler.

Also, by using the "keypress" event it will fire for each key typed (entered or deleted). Rather the event should fire when user has completed providing the input and has moved the focus to another control.

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net there are 2 main fields that you can check in the form object which are
__EVENTTARGET: The Control Which raised the event for postback

__EVENTARGUMENT: Arguments Passed

and to read them you can use :

```
 Dim eventArgument As String = IIf(Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT") = Nothing, 
 String.Empty, Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT"))
```

for more details you can check 
https://forums.asp.net/t/1252181.aspx?Retreiving+Argument+from+_doPostBack+in+VB